# Selenium webdriver & powershell to highlight text from one element, copy it, and then paste

Tags: powershell, selenium

So I need to highlight text from an element (textarea), copy that highlighted and then paste it into another element.

Storing the value from the first element and then populate the other element using SendKeys is not an option for me. Because then I will run into other issues with a javascript.

This is an example on how far I've got so far:

```
# Creating FirefoxDriver
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver

# Go to made up URL
$driver.url = "https://www.madeupdomain.com/"

# Find element and store in $MyElement
$MyElement = $driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='MadeUpTextAreaElementId']")

# Attempt to highlight all
$MyElement.SendKeys($driver.keys.CONTROL + 'A')

# Attempt to copy text from text
$MyElement.SendKeys($driver.keys.CONTROL + 'C')

# Find another element to paste text to
$MyOtherElement = $driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='AnotherMadeUpTextAreaElementId']"

# Attempt to paste copied text to another element
$MyOtherElement.SendKeys($driver.keys.CONTROL + 'V')
```

But this will simply type in "A" and "C" into the first element, and then "V" into the the last element.

Guessing the issue is with the "$driver.keys.CONTROL" parts. How do I get Selenium to understand it's a keycombo I want to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I started out wrong regarding "$driver.keys.CONTROL" being the issue.

"$driver.keys.CONTROL" is nowhere near the solution!

In order to simulate ctrl + a, ctrl + c, and ctrl + v in Powershell you need to use System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys. A list of all available keystrokes using this may be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Secondly in order to use these keystrokes with a Selenium webdriver I used the SendKeys methods from OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions. Which I discovered after looking into a couple of java related threads. Took me some time to convert into Powershell friendly code:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...)

So anyway here is my code updating, doing the ctrl + a, ctrl + c, and ctrl + v actions I needed:

```
# Creating FirefoxDriver
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver

# Create instans of Actions
$actions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions($driver)

# Go to made up URL
$driver.url = "https://www.madeupdomain.com/"

# Find element and store in $MyElement
$MyElement = $driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='MadeUpTextAreaElementId']")

# Attempt to highlight all
$actions.SendKeys($MyElement,[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^a")) | out-null

# Attempt to copy text from text
$actions.SendKeys($MyElement,[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^c")) | out-null

# Find another element to paste text to
$MyOtherElement = $driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='AnotherMadeUpTextAreaElementId']"

# Attempt to paste copied text to another element
$actions.SendKeys($MyElement,[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^v")) | out-null
```

Just make sure you have your browser window on focus when using System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys! I did the mistake to have my powershell prompt selected during some runs, which caused unnecessarily troubleshooting.